A 2-coloring of a bipartite graph such that one of the partitions contains exactly k vertices
Given the efficient solvability of the $2$-coloring problem in bipartite graphs, I claim that the this problem can be accomplished within polynomial time.
A algorithm for solving this problem involves calculating the cardinalities of the partition sets for each connected component, starting from every vertex in that component. By conducting a breadth-first search from each vertex, we can obtain a (potentially non-unique) $2$-coloring of the connected component. Subsequently, summing the cardinalities of all partition sets across the entire bipartite graph enables us to determine if there exists a partition with exactly $k$ vertices.
For instance, consider a bipartite graph with two connected components, $C$ and $CC$. For each vertex in $C$, we apply a breadth-first search-based $2$-coloring algorithm and record the corresponding partition set cardinalities (e.g., $\{3, 8, \ldots\}$). We repeat this process for $CC$ (e.g., obtaining $\{5, 10, \ldots\}$). To determine if a partition with $k$ vertices exists, we can search for pairs of cardinalities (one from each set) whose sum equals $k$. This can be efficiently achieved using a Cartesian product followed by a summation check.
Do you think there is a better algorithm to solve the same problem?
Is there any reference to this problem (a published article or a conference: I'm not looking for a book, but an article or proceedings)?
Thanks in advance...

This is a straight-forward dynamic programming exercise similar to subset sum.
Let $(A_1, B_1), (A_2, B_2), \dots, (A_p, B_p)$ be the sides of partitions $A$ and $B$ in connected component $i$.
Now, you create a dynamic programming table $\text{DP}[i, t]$ that stores whether it is possible to have a bipartite graph with exactly $t$ vertices on one side using the $i$ first components.  Using the recurrence
$$\text{DP}[i, t] = \text{DP}[i-1][t-A_i] \lor \text{DP}[i-1][t-B_i],$$
you correctly decides whether there is a partitioning you are after by examining $\text{DP}[p, k]$.  I believe the running time should be bounded by $O(nk)$.
